# Spring Cloud Config Client connecting to RabbitMQ

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I have been trying to set up a Spring Cloud Config Server/Client. I have been following a few different examples ([1](http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/spring-cloud.html#_spring_cloud_config), [2](http://qiita.com/making@github/items/704d8e254e03c5cce546)). I have the client and server set up correctly and can successfully query localhost:8888/localhost:8080 to see the values in JSON format.

My question is whether Spring Boot will automatically detect these properties provided by Spring Cloud Config Server. For now I am just attempting to connect to a RabbitMQ instance on startup but have had no success despite not having any errors. It does not connect to Rabbit or create the queues/exchanges.

It works when I have an application.properties file locally with the following properties but I wish to get these setting through Spring Cloud Config from a GitHub repository.

```
spring.rabbitmq.host=178.61.47.---
spring.rabbitmq.port=5672
spring.rabbitmq.username=mqtt
spring.rabbitmq.password=mqtt
```

I have looked through the questions here/issues on GitHub but can't see anything relating to this.

Code for client class is below:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
@SpringBootApplication
public class ConfigRabbitApplication {

    final static String queueName = "arduino-weather-queue";

    @Autowired
    RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

    @Bean
    Queue queue() {
        return new Queue(queueName, true);
    }

    @Bean
    Binding binding(Queue queue, TopicExchange exchange) {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange).with("arduino-weather");
    }

    @Bean
    TopicExchange exchange() {
        return new TopicExchange("arduino-iot-exchange", true, false);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ConfigRabbitApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: do you have a project that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Hi Spencer I uploaded my code for a [ConfigClient](https://github.com/martinod1/ConfigClient) and [ConfigServer](https://github.com/martinod1/ConfigServer) to GitHub here

Comment: Are you trying to read config from RabbitMQ ?

Answer (score 0):

No, spring boot client is not aware that you want to fetch configuration from config-server. That is probably loaded when specific class in on a classpath, thats why you have to add `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config` dependency. Its well described here: http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/spring-cloud-config.html#_client_side_usage

In case config-server is not on localhost:8888 you will also have to add:

```
spring.cloud.config.uri: http://myconfigserver.com
```

to your bootstrap.yml file ( its same as application.yml, just loaded earlier ).

Comment: I already have the `spring-cloud-starter-config` dependency added and am able to use @Value annotation to display the properties from the file on GitHub. What I want to do is to replace the properties which I would normally host locally (in application.properties) with the values from the file on GitHub.

Comment: under which url exactly can you view this properties? Its important regarding which profile/application name is used. It should be configured in bootstrap.yml file like here: http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/spring-cloud-config.html#_environment_repository

Comment: I can view the properties under localhost:8888/rabbitconfig/master. Rabbitconfig is both the name given in bootstrap.yml in the client and the name of the properties file on GitHub.However I am unable to have these properties used within the app on startup as I wish as when I run RabbitMQ it is not connected.